# Docker on Windows Server 2016 TP4 Downloading git in container through powershell

Tags: windows, git, powershell, azure, docker

I have an angular UI and a nodejs api. I am currently running windows server 2016 TP4 in Azure.Here are the steps I go through:

1. I am able to remote in, create images, create containers based off those images, and attach to those containers no problem.
2. I pulled a nodejs image from docker: `docker pull microsoft/node` and then created a container from that image: `docker run --name 'my_api_name' -it microsoft/node cmd`
3. That command takes me into the container via a windows command prompt. I type `powershell` which takes me into a powershell shell and i can run npm commands.

   My question is, **how do I install git onto this container?** I want to reach out to the repository holding my app, pull it down and run it in this container. I will eventually push this container image up to the docker registry so clients can pull it down and run it on their windows env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this in admin shell:

```
iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
cinst -y git
```

Comment: I'll take a look at this and 'git' back to you ;) @majkinetor

Comment: that works, thank you so much. There is not a lot of information out there in regards to this...

Comment: I am happy it worked. People usually do not know about choco for some reason. BTW, you can accept the answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you wouldn't add git to the container and try to pull your repo into it (that will also get messy with credentials for private repos

You should do your source control management on your host and then build the source code into a container. It's not yet there for the Windows Dockerfiles, but the [Linux ones have ONBUILD](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/baad247b9df8087d4c13a3a9bfb3c65833f424bb/5.10/onbuild/Dockerfile). It should be possible to replicate that for Windows.

Comment: Still, the method I provided is general and he might need a git in the container for other reasons, such as delivering updates .

Comment: the truth is I ended up using @majkinetor answer to install git on the host then used the dockerfile to build the apps into containers. but fiism is also right about how to move the files into the container. There are much more underlying problems in general with windows server TP4 that have made docker and windows a pain.

Comment: @ssl I'd love to hear your comments, feel free to email michael.friis@docker.com

Comment: @friism all the problems were related to TP4. Like not being able to map ports between container host and container and then see your app running when you hit container host ip in browser. After struggling for days to get npm to work in a container, i run into that error of not being able to map ports. HUGE buzz kill. I see TP5 is out and hear those errors are now fixed and am looking forwrd to trying it out...I will keep your email handy, however!!

Answer (score 0):

```
RUN @powershell iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))   
RUN cinst -y git
```

Refer: [Unable to install git and python packages inside Windows container](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/45f612a8-431c-48f3-bc9e-b268e008644d/unable-to-install-git-and-python-packages-inside-windows-container?forum=windowscontainers)

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by downloading the "Portable" version of Git.  Copying those files into the container and ***then running the post installation script provided by Git.

Find appropriate download here: https://git-scm.com/download/win

Inside docker file:

ADD Git64/ C:/Git/

WORKDIR C:/Git/

RUN %windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Git\post-install.bat