# Setup git via windows docker file

Tags: dockerfile, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop, docker

I write `Dockerfile` which is based on [windowsnanoserver](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/nanoserver/). I need to add to this image git. In order to achieve it I did the following:

```
RUN Invoke-WebRequest 'https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.12.2.windows.2/Git-2.12.2.2-64-bit.exe'
RUN Invoke-Expression "c:\Git-2.12.2.2-64-bit.exe"
```

But when I execute this lines via docker build, I receive following error message:

> Invoke-Expression : The term 'c:\Git-2.12.2.2-64-bit.exe' is not
>   recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
>   program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
>   verify that the path is correct and try again.

I realize that this error message indicates that due to console nature of windows docker images I'll not be able to execute GUI installers. Unfortunately git doesn't have console installer. [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) works fine under [windowsservercore](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/windowsservercore/) image but doesn't work at [windowsnanoserver](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/nanoserver/). In order to install git for [windowsnanoserver](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/nanoserver/) I have idea to repeat in `Dockerfile` commands from [chocolatey git installer](https://chocolatey.org/packages/git.install) which is fine for me, but still I'd like to know is there any simpler way to install git on [windowsnanoserver](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/nanoserver/)?

Comment: Please view: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36750554/docker-on-windows-server-2016-tp4-downloading-git-in-container-through-powershel/65283828#65283828

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've solved issue with GUI through usage of MinGit and by putting information about mingit into environment/path variable. I've used following approach:

```
RUN Invoke-WebRequest 'https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.12.2.windows.2/MinGit-2.12.2.2-64-bit.zip' -OutFile MinGit.zip

RUN Expand-Archive c:\MinGit.zip -DestinationPath c:\MinGit; \
$env:PATH = $env:PATH + ';C:\MinGit\cmd\;C:\MinGit\cmd'; \
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\' -Name Path -Value $env:PATH
```

Comment: If someone is looking for the portable ZIP file of Git's current version, it is https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.40.1.windows.1/MinGit-2.40.1-64-bit.zip. Future releases will be available in the page https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/

Answer (score 5):

You are correct, both Windows and Linux containers generally focus on running headless applications (i.e. without GUI).

It sounds like you want to create a container image based on the nanoserver image that has git?

Chocolatey is a great idea.

If you give me the broader context of your goals I can help you further.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 5):

Installing using Chocolatey worked for me, per this image: [ehong](https://hub.docker.com/r/ehong/git-windows-server)

I added these lines to my Dockerfile:

```
ENV ChocolateyUseWindowsCompression false 
RUN powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force
RUN powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"
RUN choco install git.install -y --no-progress
```

To clone more complex repos with submodule dependencies, for example `git clone --recursive -b v1.42.0 https://github.com/grpc/grpc.git`, include the remainder of the [ehong](https://hub.docker.com/r/ehong/git-windows-server) Dockerfile:

```
# Install NuGet provider
RUN powershell -Command "Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force -Scope AllUsers -RequiredVersion 2.8.5.201 -ErrorAction Stop"
# Set the PSGallery as a trusted repository
RUN powershell -Command "Set-PSRepository -Name PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted"
#Install posh-git
RUN powershell Install-Module -Name 'posh-git'
```

Answer (score 2):

Call the git.setup.exe installation file with the parameters /? to list all possible switches.

To run a silent installation:
git.setup.exe /VERYSILENT /NORESTART /NOCANCEL /SP- /CLOSEAPPLICATIONS /RESTARTAPPLICATIONS

To do a customized installation:

run manually git installation with the parameter /SAVEINF="filename"

e.g:. git-2.xx.exe /SAVEINF="filename"

And then to repeat the installation with /LOADINF="filename"

e.g.: git.setup.exe /VERYSILENT /NORESTART /NOCANCEL /SP- /CLOSEAPPLICATIONS /RESTARTAPPLICATIONS /LOADINF="filename"

It's documented on:
[Git: Silent-or-Unattended-Installation](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/Silent-or-Unattended-Installation)

Answer (score 0):

You can download and use the Git Thumbdrive edition:
https://git-scm.com/download/win

look for the link under:

Git for Windows Portable ("thumbdrive edition")

E.G.: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.23.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.23.0-64-bit.7z.exe

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of @Mariusz, the following lines install git into Windows image

```
    # copy inf file
COPY resources/git-install.inf c:\git-install.inf
# get Git install file
RUN Invoke-WebRequest 'https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.30.1.windows.1/Git-2.30.1-64-bit.exe' -OutFile 'git.exe'; `
# install Git
    Start-Process "c:\git.exe" -ArgumentList '/SP-', '/VERYSILENT', '/NORESTART', '/NOCANCEL', '/CLOSEAPPLICATIONS', '/RESTARTAPPLICATIONS', '/LOADINF=git-install.inf' -Wait -NoNewWindow; `
# delete files
    Remove-Item -Force git-install.inf; `
    Remove-Item -Force git.exe;
```